# Not able to make an ajax call by CROS Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I am get below error while making a CROS request. Can any one please let me know If I am missing any other settings?

Error on Console :  ***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)***

Settings done on web.config on local host application.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Content-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />                 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

My Ajax Call

```
var favoriteWebPartFeedsUrl = 'http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.History.Case&RenderAs=feed&ContentType=xml'   
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url:favoriteWebPartFeedsUrl,
    dataType: "json",   
    processdata: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Favorite webpart is loaded", response);;
    },
    error: function (e) {                
        console.log('Featching Favorite webpart FAILED');
    }   
});
```

Comment: 401 (Unauthorized) - such error comes when requested resource is behind authentication/log-in mechanism. Try putting `http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.History.Case&RenderAs=feed&ContentType=xml` URL into your browser tab and check whether you are able to see the page or you get redirected to Login page?

Comment: @vijayP : yes. I am able to get the data when I put this into my browser URL

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of adding multiple reference to jquery libraries.

Error was because of

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Fixed by removing multiple jquery references and keeping a single one.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```